# Attempt to get argmax of an empty sequence fix leads to maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, numpy, recursion

I get the following error when I try to run my program:

```
  self.root = self._build_tree(X, y)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\virat\OneDrive\Desktop\projects\DecisionTree\decisionTree.py", line 73, in _build_tree
    left_child = self._build_tree(X[left_idx, :], y[left_idx], depth + 1)  
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   
  [Previous line repeated 8 more times]
  File "C:\Users\virat\OneDrive\Desktop\projects\DecisionTree\decisionTree.py", line 74, in _build_tree
    right_child = self._build_tree(X[right_idx, :], y[right_idx], depth + 1)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\virat\OneDrive\Desktop\projects\DecisionTree\decisionTree.py", line 64, in _build_tree
    most_common_Label = np.argmax(np.bincount(y))
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in argmax
  File "C:\Users\virat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 1216, in argmax
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'argmax', axis=axis, out=out, **kwds)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\virat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 57, in _wrapfunc
    return bound(*args, **kwds)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: attempt to get argmax of an empty sequence
```

I am aware that this can be bypassed by adding a check for size of `y` but this further leads to this error-

```
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  [Previous line repeated 975 more times]
  File "C:\Users\virat\OneDrive\Desktop\projects\DecisionTree\decisionTree.py", line 72, in _build_tree
    left_idx, right_idx = self._create_split(X[:, best_feat], best_thresh)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\virat\OneDrive\Desktop\projects\DecisionTree\decisionTree.py", line 25, in _create_split
    left_idx = np.argwhere(X <= thresh).flatten()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in argwhere
  File "C:\Users\virat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 624, in argwhere
    return transpose(nonzero(a))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in transpose
  File "C:\Users\virat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 660, in transpose
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'transpose', axes)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\virat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 54, in _wrapfunc
    return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\virat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 43, in _wrapit
    result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Here is my necessary code-

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

class Node:
    def __init__(self, feature=None, threshold=None, left=None, right =None, *, value=None):
        self.feature = feature
        self.threshold = threshold
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.value = value        
        
class decisionTree:
    def __init__(self, max_depth=100, min_samples_per_split=2):
        self.max_depth = max_depth
        self.min_samples_per_split = min_samples_per_split
        self.root = None
        
    def _is_finished(self, depth):
        if (depth >= self.max_depth
            or self.n_class_labels == 1
            or self.n_samples < self.min_samples_per_split):
            return True
        return False
    
    def _create_split(self, X, thresh):
        # argwhere splits the data points in two areas in an optimal manner
        left_idx = np.argwhere(X <= thresh).flatten()
        right_idx = np.argwhere(X > thresh).flatten()
        return left_idx, right_idx
    
    def _information_gain(self, X, y, thresh):
        parent_loss = self._entropy(y)
        left_idx, right_idx = self._create_split(X, thresh)
        n, n_left, n_right = len(y), len(left_idx), len(right_idx)
        
        if n_left == 0 or n_right == 0:
            return 0
        
        child_loss = (n_left / n) * self._entropy(y[left_idx]) + (n_right / n) * self._entropy(y[right_idx])
        return parent_loss - child_loss
    
    def _best_split(self, X, y, features):
        split = {'score':-1, 'feat': None, 'thresh': None}
        for feat in features:
            X_feat = X[:, feat]
            thresholds = np.unique(X_feat)
            for thresh in thresholds:
                score = self._information_gain(X_feat, y, thresh)
                if score > split['score']:
                    split['score'] = score
                    split['feat'] = feat
                    split['thresh'] = thresh
                    
        return split['feat'], split['thresh']
    
    def _entropy(self, y):
        # bincount creates a frequency array of +ve integers upto the maximum integer
        proportions = np.bincount(y) / len(y)
        entropy = -np.sum([p * np.log2(p) for p in proportions if p > 0])
        return entropy
    
    def _build_tree(self, X, y, depth=0):
        self.n_samples, self.n_features = X.shape
        self.n_class_labels = len(np.unique(y))

        # stopping condition
        if self._is_finished(depth):
        #if self._is_finished(depth) and np.size(y) != 0:           # leads to maximum recursion depth exceeded error
            most_common_Label = np.argmax(np.bincount(y))
            return Node(value=most_common_Label)

        # get best split
        rnd_feats = np.random.choice(self.n_features, self.n_features, replace=False)
        best_feat, best_thresh = self._best_split(X, y, rnd_feats)

        # grow children recursively
        left_idx, right_idx = self._create_split(X[:, best_feat], best_thresh)
        left_child = self._build_tree(X[left_idx, :], y[left_idx], depth + 1)
        right_child = self._build_tree(X[right_idx, :], y[right_idx], depth + 1)
        return Node(best_feat, best_thresh, left_child, right_child)

    def fit(self, x, y):
        self.root = self._build_tree(x, y)
        
def main():
    data = datasets.load_breast_cancer()
    x, y = data.data, data.target

    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
        x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1
    )
    clf = decisionTree(max_depth=10)
    clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please include all the necessary code and data needed to reproduce the error.

Comment: Telling us about `X` and `y` might help.  From their indexing I'm guessing one is 2d, the other 1d.  For the `argmax` line, I'd check the `y.shape` (and `dtype`), and also check `bincount(y)` by itself, before trying to do the `argmax`.  If `y` has 0 shape, so will `bincount`.  Where does the `recursion` error occur?

Comment: What is the stopping condition if `len(y)==0`?

Comment: @hpaulj  Like I said earlier, adding checks for the size and shape of y results in a `maximum recursion depth exceeded` error which I have expanded on in the post now.

Comment: You're going to need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). No one on SO will go through a large code to find your issue because that is too time-consuming. Please simplify the problem into something manageable for this site.

Comment: you/we need to know what `X <= thresh` is like.  I've never seen a recursion error in `np.nonzero`.

Comment: @hpaulj I added a wrong comment there, my bad for misguiding you. `threshold` is simply the most common data points/columns which is used to find out the optimal split of data in a decision tree, atleast that is what I am aware of from my fundamental knowledge. You can refer to the link if I was not good at explaining: https://archive.is/ltrqu

Comment: Alright the issue was caused by my not declaring a value for the `score` key in `split` dict in `best_split` function. Thank you for your time and energy spent.